# Running Python from Amazon Web Service Ec2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was hoping I could get some direction about creating a website using AWS that will run a python script. I created an EC2 Instance running Ubuntu and made it talk with a relational database made with the same account.

In a nutshell, the site I am creating is a YouTube Library of captions. The user will input a title and AWS will retrieve links to XML documents that contains the captions to the related videos from YouTube. I would like to know where and how to run a Python script to scrape the text from these XML documents every time a user makes a request.

My research has taken me in multiple directions, but I am not sure what is best for my purpose. For example, I am trying to run a remote script from GitHub, but don't know if there's a better way to store the script?

It's my first time working with AWS so please keep explanations simple. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please be specific about the issue?

Comment: Yes, I think my main issue is my lack of experience with AWS. I think a Python web framework could work for my project. How can I integrate this with ec2 instance, rds, etc?

Comment: The fact that your application will run on an Amazon EC2 server has no impact on the design of your system. You can write it just the same as you would for a computer under your desk. However, the application might benefit from using _other_ AWS services such as a database, queueing service, notification service, etc.